# Settings not set after calling register_setting()

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api, activation

I have a plugin with an activation hooked function. This function has to register 4 setting variables.

I can't see why, but only the first setting is registered correctly, the last 3 are somehow skipped.

This is the plugin main file:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  Integrazione Liferay
Version:      1.1.0
Text Domain:  integrazione-liferay
*/

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'integrazione_liferay_activate');
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'integrazione_liferay_deactivate');
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'integrazione_liferay_uninstall');

//Funzione di attivazione plugin
function integrazione_liferay_activate() {
    // Registro variabile che indica se il cron deve essere attivo
    if (get_option('integrazione_liferay_cron_enabled') === false) {
        $args = array(
            'type' => 'integer', 
            'default' => 0,
        );
        register_setting( 'integrazione_liferay_options', 'integrazione_liferay_cron_enabled', $args ); 
    }
    update_option( 'integrazione_liferay_cron_enabled', 1);

    // Registro variabile che indica se è necessario riscrivere i permalinks
    if (get_option('integrazione_liferay_flush_permalinks') === false) {
        $args = array(
            'type' => 'integer', 
            'default' => 0,
        );
        register_setting( 'integrazione_liferay_options', 'integrazione_liferay_flush_permalinks', $args ); 
    }
    update_option( 'integrazione_liferay_flush_permalinks', 0);

    // Registro variabile che indica l'ultimo timestamp elaborato
    if (get_option('integrazione_liferay_last_timestamp') === false) {
        $args = array(
            'type' => 'integer', 
            'default' => 0,
        );
        register_setting( 'integrazione_liferay_options', 'integrazione_liferay_last_timestamp', $args ); 
    }
    update_option( 'integrazione_liferay_last_timestamp', 0);

    // Registro variabile che memorizza il csv serializzato
    if (get_option('integrazione_liferay_csv_data') === false) {
        $args = array(
            'type' => 'string', 
            'default' => "",
        );
        register_setting( 'integrazione_liferay_options', 'integrazione_liferay_csv_data', $args ); 
    }
    update_option( 'integrazione_liferay_csv_data', "");
}

// Funzione di disattivazione plugin
function integrazione_liferay_deactivate() {
    // Disabilito creazione nuovi cron
    update_option( 'integrazione_liferay_cron_enabled', 0);
    // De-schedulo tutti i cron già schedulati
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'integrazione_liferay_cron_hook' );
    while ($timestamp) {
        wp_unschedule_event( $timestamp, 'integrazione_liferay_cron_hook' );
        $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'integrazione_liferay_cron_hook' );
    }
}

// Funzione di disinstallazione plugin
function integrazione_liferay_uninstall() {
    // Eseguo disattivazione preventiva
    integrazione_liferay_deactivate();
    // Rimuovo i settings
    unregister_setting( 'integrazione_liferay_options', 'integrazione_liferay_cron_enabled' ); 
    unregister_setting( 'integrazione_liferay_options', 'integrazione_liferay_flush_permalinks' ); 
    unregister_setting( 'integrazione_liferay_options', 'integrazione_liferay_last_timestamp' ); 
    unregister_setting( 'integrazione_liferay_options', 'integrazione_liferay_csv_data' ); 
}
```

I tried debugging the piece by deactivating and re-activating the plugin. The debugger actually tries to set the last 3 settings each time as `get_option()` on those 3 will always return `false` on every activation. This is the debugging result (GIF):

[image: debugging]

And this is the resulting `/options.php` after the activation:

[image: options.php]

I have used this settings pattern in some other plugins but I can't wrap my head around this one's behavior.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: I don't think you've understood what `register_setting` does. It's supposed to be run in `admin_init`, not just on activation, and is for building options pages with the [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/).

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for pointing this out. It might be an unproper usage of settings, but nonetheless I would expect them to set. Anyway I admit I'm quite rookie at this so, would using options suitable for my purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`register_setting` does not insert anything in the database. It's supposed to be run in `admin_init`, not just on activation, and is for building options pages with the [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/) and handles things like sanitisation and permissions when saving options in the admin.

If you want to add some default option values to the database on activation, use [`add_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/). It will add the option and value to the database, but only if there isn't already a value for that option:

```
function integrazione_liferay_activate() {
    add_option( 'integrazione_liferay_cron_enabled', 1 );
    add_option( 'integrazione_liferay_flush_permalinks', 0 );
    add_option( 'integrazione_liferay_last_timestamp', 0 );
    add_option( 'integrazione_liferay_csv_data', '' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this straight away. Still, I'm very puzzled about why did the first value insert.

Comment: Perfect! Anyway, according to the codex, update_option() should have created the values anyway... But since the whole piece was kinda bogus I guess we'll never know what happened. Thanks again! ☺